# Why do some of my lookup fields have type-ahead in the UI?

Tags: lookup-column

(And how can I get all of my lookup fields to have type ahead?)

So here is the weird thing: I have several lists and lookups which I am deploying as a part of a .wsp.

Of all of the lookups that are deployed, *one* gets this nice little type-ahead feature in the UI which I thought I had to add a third party JavaScript library to accomplish.

See evidence below:

[image: Snapshot of the mystery field in action]

To be clear, this is **not** a managed metadata field; it's a regular lookup field.  But the markup is definitely different in the HTML.  It renders as a `input type=textbox` and `img` which overlays a `select`

[image: Markup]

To wit, I have not been able to get any of my other lookup fields to behave this way.  Only this one.

So my question is what is the magic sauce that allows me to get this behavior "for free"?

Answer (score 3):

If the lookup list has more than 20 items, SharePoint will change to the type-ahead rendering style.

Comment: Why is my lookup field not rendering typeahead? (the list has thousands of items)